# Optimization problem with Pandas apply and multiIndex search

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, apply, multi-index

So, I was wondering if I am doing this correctly, because maybe there is a much better way to do this and I am wasting a lot of time.

I have a 3 level index dataframe, like this:

```
IndexA IndexB IndexC   ColumnA  ColumnB
   A      B      C1      HiA     HiB
   A      B      C2      HiA2    HiB2
```

I need to do a search for every row, saving data from other rows. I know this sounds strange, but it makes sense with my data. For example:
I want to add `ColumnB` data from my second row to the first one, and vice-versa, like this:

```
IndexA IndexB IndexC   ColumnA  ColumnB  NewData
   A      B      C1      HiA     HiB       HiB2
   A      B      C2      HiA2    HiB2      HiB
```

In order to do this search, I do an `apply` on my `df`, like this:

```
df['NewData'] = df.apply(lambda r: my_function(df, r.IndexA, r.IndexB, r.IndexC), axis=1)
```

Where my function is:

```
def my_function(df, indexA, indexB, indexC):
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    #Here I do calculations (substraction) to know what C exactly I want
    #newIndexC = C - someConstantValue
    try:
        res = df.loc[idx[IndexA, IndexB, newIndexC],'ColumnB']
        return res
    except KeyError:
        return -1
```

I tried to simplify a lot of this problem, sorry if it sounds confusing. Basically my data frame has 20 million rows, and this search takes 2 hours. I know it has to take a lot, because there are a lot of accesses, but I wanted to know if there could be a faster way to do this search.

**More information:**

- On indexA I have different groups of values. Example: Countries.
- On indexB I have different groups of dates.
- On indexC I have different groups of values.

**Answer:**

```
df['NewData'] = df.groupby(level=['IndexA', 'IndexB'])['ColumnB'].shift(7)
```

Comment: Instead of modifiying indices, I would suggest you to add new `new_ColumnB` and `new_ColumnC` columns according to your formulla. And in the end set the new index.

Comment: @has I can't do that, the point of modify the index C is to know if it exists or not. If I add a new columns, it will exists, and I will get wrong data.

Comment: The entire interesting part of your problem is the part you've elided ("Here I do calculations").  Please include that.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I wrote it, it is just a substraction of C - a constat value. No more calculations are done there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're really doing is a shift.  You can speed it up 1000x like this:

```
df['NewData'] = df['ColumnB'].shift(-someConstantValue)
```

You'll need to roll the data from the top `someConstantValue` number of rows around to the bottom--I'm leaving that as an exercise.

Comment: My bad, I can't use shift because I would mix data. I added more information in the question. Hope it is clearer now, sorry!

Comment: Thinking about this, I found that I totally missexplained this problem, thus this is not the solution. Should I edit this one? Create a new ask?

Comment: Just create a new question and post a link to it in a comment here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260741/optimization-problem-with-pandas-apply-and-multiindex-search
Here it is! Thank you for your time.